# Modify the code (summarize the code)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a very large data set including 200 variables (columns), I am looking for a way (Loop function, lapply,etc) to have multiple variables in the same plot. How can I modify the below code to have this kind of plot (instead of repeating each `geom_line(aes(y=))` for each `W`?

```
A<-seq( 0, 9, 1 )
B<-seq( 30, 39, 1 )
W1<-seq( 0.3, 1.2, 0.1 )
r<-seq( 32, 41, 1 )
f<-seq( 33, 42, 1 )
W2<-seq( 1.3, 2.2, 0.1 )
g<-seq( 34, 43, 1 )
W3<-seq( 4.3, 5.2, 0.1 )
s<-data.frame( A, B, W1, r, f, W2, g, W3 )
ggplot( s, aes( x = A, y = B) ) + geom_point() + geom_line( aes( y = W1 ) ) +
    geom_line( aes( y = W2 ) ) +
    geom_line( aes( y = W3 ) ) + theme_bw()
```

Comment: Surely there are worked examples of using `for`-loops to `print` multiple ggplot-objects. What kind of searching have you done? I found "921 results" when I did that search. Maybe you ought to delete your answer and then only undelete it if you cannot find the answer with a search.

Comment: @ 42, Thanks for the comment. I could not find the answer of my question.

Comment: I would suggest to adjust the title of your question. Currently, it is not very specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you invest a little time to familiarize yourself with the set of packages commonly known as `tidyverse`. A highly recommended and comprehensible introduction is the free online book ["R for datascience"](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/).

Specifically, to answer your question, I would firstly cast the dataframe into 'long' form, and then plot each variable against `A` using an aesthetic mapping based on color:

```
library("tidyverse")
A<-seq(0,9,1)
B<-seq(30,39,1)
m1<-seq(0.3,1.2,0.1)
r<-seq(32,41,1)
f<-seq(33,42,1)
m2<-seq(1.3,2.2,0.1)
g<-seq(34,43,1)
m3<-seq(4.3,5.2,0.1)
s<-data.frame(A,B,m1,r,f,m2,g,m3)

data <- s %>% gather(var, value, B:m3)
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=value, color =var)) + geom_point()
```

(I fixed typos in your code example)

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. Definitely, I will have a look at this package but I cannot use in for my question. In reality, I have a large dataset and sometimes there are a lot of columns among m1,m2,m3. So I cannot use something like B:m3.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to plot only m1,m2,m3? in that case: `data <- s %>% gather(var, value, m1,m2,m3)
ggplot(data, aes(x=A, y=value, color =var)) + geom_point()`

Comment: In my real data set, I have m1 to m20 (variables with a pattern in their names). So I am looking for function/loop function to summarize the code instead of  writing  m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,,,,,,,m20. And as I mentioned, these variables are not successive.

Comment: Your question has two components (and little to do with its current title): One  part is how to plot several variables without listing them explicitly. The answer is above. The second part deals with identifying the variables without selecting them actively. Here, I would suggest (again) to familiarize yourself with the `tidyverse`. A straightforward approach would be to take the approach above, and extend the pipeline with a filtering step, along the lines of `%>% filter(stringr::str_detect(var, 'm.*'))`

Answer (score 1):

`ggplot` works best with data in long format. For reshaping from wide to long, `melt()` from the `data.table` package is used here.

```
library(data.table)
molten <- setDT(melt(s, id.vars = "A"))
head(molten, 12)
#    A variable value
# 1: 0        B  30.0
# 2: 1        B  31.0
# 3: 2        B  32.0
# 4: 3        B  33.0
# 5: 4        B  34.0
# 6: 5        B  35.0
# 7: 6        B  36.0
# 8: 7        B  37.0
# 9: 8        B  38.0
#10: 9        B  39.0
#11: 0       W1   0.3
#12: 1       W1   0.4
```

Now, variables can be plotted all at once:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(molten, aes(A, value, group = variable, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

or selectively:

```
ggplot(molten[variable %in% letters], aes(A, value, group = variable, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

or selectively as points or lines:

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(A, value, group = variable, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point(data = molten[variable %in% c("B")]) + 
  geom_line(data = molten[variable %like% "^W"]) + theme_bw()
```

[image]